# what is the purpose of the frequency domain analysis

Tags: web-audio-api

I had assumed that this was going to output a set frequency buckets that I could use to do pitch detection (like aubio pitch). But that doesn't seem to be what it does. I fired up the voice-omatic app and using it frequency display played various notes through my mic. Bars appear, all at the left hand end, almost no distinction between high and low notes. I upped the FFT size just to see if that changed anything, seems not. I found a picthdetect js project and saw that it used analyzer ,aha, here I will find the correct usage, but the meat of the code doesn't use frequency domain output, it feeds time domain into its own algorithm. So to solve my problem I will use that library, but I am still curious what the freqency domain data represents

Answer (score 0):

It does exactly what you think it does, but the specific implementation on that site is not great for seeing that.

The values are mapped differently than is nescessary for seeing changes in pitch between high and low vocal range because the range is mapped linearly, not logrithmically. If you were to map each frequency bin in a logarithmic way you would get a far more useful diagram. Right now the right hand 3/4 of the visualizer is showing from 5000hz to 20000hz (roughly), which contains very very little data in an audio signal compared to 0-5000hz. The root frequency of the human voice (and most instruments) occupies mostly between 100-1000hz. There are harmonics above that, but at reducing amplitudes the higher you get.

I've tweaked the code to tell you the peak frequency and the size of each bucket. Use this app.js: https://puu.sh/Izcws/ded6aae55b.js - you can use a tone generator on your phone to see how accurate it is. https://puu.sh/Izcx3/d5a9d74764.png

The way the code works is it calculates how big each bucket is as described in my answer with `var bucketSize = 1 / (analyser.fftSize / analyser.context.sampleRate);` (and adds two spans to show the data) and then while drawing each bar calculate which bar is the biggest, and then multiply the size of each bucket by which bucket is the biggest to get the peak frequency (and write it in `el2`). You can play with the fftSize and see why using a small value will not work at all for determining whether you are playing A2(110 Hz) or A2#(116.5 Hz).

From `https://stackoverflow.com/a/43369065/13801789`:

I believe I understand what you mean exactly. The problem is not with your code, it is with the FFT underlying `getByteFrequencyData`. The core problem is that musical **notes are logarithmically spaced** while the **FFT frequency bins are linearly spaced**.

*Notes are logarithmically spaced:* The difference between consecutive low notes, say **A2**(110 Hz) and **A2#**(116.5 Hz) is 6.5 Hz while the difference between the same 2 notes on a higher octave **A3**(220 Hz) and **A3#**(233.1 Hz) is 13.1 Hz.

*FFT bins are linearly spaced:* Say we're working with 44100 samples per second, the FFT takes a window of 1024 samples (a wave), and multiplies it first with a wave as long as 1024 samples (let's call it **wave1**), so that would be a period of `1024/44100=0.023 seconds` which is `43.48 Hz`, and puts the resulting amplitude in the first bin. Then it multiplies it with a wave with frequency of **wave1** * 2, which is `86.95 Hz`, then **wave1** * 3 = `130.43 Hz`. So the difference between the frequencies is linear; it's always the same = 43.48, unlike the difference in musical notes which changes.

This is why close low notes will be bundled up in the same bin while close high notes are separated. This is the problem with FFT's frequency resolution. It can be solved by taking windows bigger than 1024 samples, but that would be a trade off for the time resolution.

Comment: here is the code i was referring to https://mdn.github.io/voice-change-o-matic/ , it is the main sample for webaudio input handling (vs audio generation). I have changed it to 2048 fft size and it makes no difference, just finer grained crowding at the left hand end. How do I know what frequencies are in what bucket? I can find no sample of using this interface to do pitch detection which is the obvious use case (guitar tuner for example)

Comment: It's written in the answer, each "bucket" is a linearly spaced selection of frequencies. See the paragraph starting "FFT bins are linearly spaced:". I've tweaked the code to tell you the peak frequency and the size of each bucket. Use this app.js: https://puu.sh/Izcws/ded6aae55b.js - you can use a tone generator on your phone to see how accurate it is. https://puu.sh/Izcx3/d5a9d74764.png

Comment: The way the code works is it calculates how big each bucket is as described in my answer with `var bucketSize = 1 / (analyser.fftSize / analyser.context.sampleRate);` (and adds two spans to show the data) and then while drawing each bar calculate which bar is the biggest, and then multiply the size of each bucket by which bucket is the biggest to get the peak frequency (and write it in `el2`). You can play with the fftSize and see why using a small value will not work at all for determining whether you are playing A2(110 Hz) or A2#(116.5 Hz).